# React_Redux: Pass parameter in callback during continually callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, redux, react-redux

I have problem about passing  parameter in callback function. I use `redux-form`, when I change select in `SkinList`, then it triggers `onChange` call back - `activeSkinChange` method

in `activeSkinChange`, call `handlSkinChange` that came from SkinList handlSkinChange property. 
I need to pass select value to handlSkinChange (event.target.value)

```
export default class SkinList extends Component {
  activeSkinChange = (event) => {
    this.props.handlSkinChange(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { skinList, activeSkin } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <select className="form-control" onChange={this.activeSkinChange} value={activeSkin}>
          {this.renderOptions(skinList)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

then move outside of SkinList:

```
export default class Control extends Component {
  onHandlSkinChange = (?, ?) => {

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Field
        name="skin.colors.activeSkin"
        component={activeSkin =>
        <SkinList skinList={skinList} activeSkin={activeSkin} handlSkinChange={this.onHandlSkinChange(activeSkin)}/>
      }/>
    );
  }
}
```

`handlSkinChange` will trigger callback `this.onHandlSkinChange`, 
I also need pass another parameter `activeSkin` in `this.onHandlSkinChange()` on SkinList props, but it will encounter error..

it means there are two parameters to need to pass in `onHandlSkinChange` method, one is selection value(event.target.value), another is activeSkin
How should I do let me pass parameter in callback function during continually callback function?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default class SkinList extends Component {
    activeSkinChange (event){
        this.props.handlSkinChange(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        const { skinList, activeSkin } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <select className="form-control" onChange={this.activeSkinChange.bind(this)} value={activeSkin}>
                    {this.renderOptions(skinList)}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class Control extends Component {
  onHandlSkinChange (value, activeSkin ) {
     console.log("CHECK",value,activeSkin);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Field
        name="skin.colors.activeSkin"
        component={activeSkin => <SkinList skinList={skinList} activeSkin={activeSkin}
         handlSkinChange={v=>this.onHandlSkinChange(v,activeSkin)}/>
      }/>
    );
  }
}
```